# Editing a SharePoint List View: Grouping by 2 Columns with 1 column empty

Tags: list, list-view

I have the following data in a Sharepoint list.

```
Name   Animal   Species
Tom    Dog      Corgi 
Dick   Dog      Corgi
Harry  Dog      German Shepherd
Jane   Cat      (BLANK) 
June   Cat      (BLANK) 
Jared  Cat      (BLANK)
```

I created a view that grouped by Animal, followed by Species. So the tree looks like

```
Dog
---Species: Corgi
------Tom
------Dick
---Species: German Shepherd
------Harry

Cat
---Species: 
------Jane
------June
------Jared
```

Is it possible to modify the view such that I get to Jane, June, Jared immediately after expanding Cat without having to expand an empty Species as well? Because of restrictions I don't have Sharepoint Designer on my computer, but I do have Visual Studio if I need to create a wholly custom web part (which I'm hoping I do not have to do)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: This is not possible even with SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created two views, one with a filter for an empty Species attribute, another one with a filter for the existence of a Species attribute. I then created a new page and instantiated two instances of the ListViewWebPart on the page, setting each of them to one of the views I've created beforehand.

I then used a Content Viewer web part to embed some javascript to hide some elements making the 2 web parts look like one.